# CanCan/Rolify: Read access for user on model is declined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, accessible, rolify

I use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) and [rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) to setup access rights for a Farm model.

```
# ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Create guest user aka. anonymous (not logged-in) when user is nil.
    user ||= User.new

    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else # guest user aka. anonymous
      can :read, :all
      # logged in user
      if user.has_role? :user
        can :create, Farm
        can :manage, Farm, :user_id => user.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I seed my application with some test data listed here:

```
# seeds.rb
puts 'SETTING UP DEFAULT USER LOGIN'
user1 = User.create! name: 'First User', email: 'first.user@foo.com', password: 'password'
puts 'New user created: ' << user1.name
user2 = User.create! name: 'Second User', email: 'second.user@foo.com', password: 'password'
puts 'New user created: ' << user2.name
user9 = User.create! name: 'Default Admin', email: 'admin@foo.com', password: 'password'
puts 'New user created: ' << user9.name

puts 'ADDING SPECIAL ROLES TO USERS'
# No role for user1 here.
user2.add_role! :user
user2.save!
user9.add_role :admin
user9.save!

puts 'SETTING UP SOME FARMS'
farm1 = Farm.create! name: 'User1 farm', location: 'Mexico'
farm1.user = user1
farm1.save!
puts 'New farm created: ' << farm1.name
farm2 = Farm.create! name: 'User2 farm', location: 'Bolivia'
farm2.user = user2
farm2.save!
puts 'New farm created: ' << farm2.name
farm3 = Farm.create! name: 'Nobody\'s farm', location: 'Death Valley'
puts 'New farm created: ' << farm3.name
```

I run the following command in Rails console to find out which farms can be accessed (read-only) by a user:

```
> Farm.accessible_by(Ability.new(User.find_by_name("First User"))).count
=> 3
> Farm.accessible_by(Ability.new(User.find_by_name("Second User"))).count
=> 1
> Farm.accessible_by(Ability.new(User.find_by_name("Default Admin"))).count
=> 3
```

Please note that user1 does not have a role assigned.

**Question:** Why does user2 not have access to all the farms as defined in `ability.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to learn the hard way that the **order** in which you define abilities **matters**! The [documentation of CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence) reveals the details for everybody to read through. In short:

> Generic rules go first, restrictive rules follow.

Here are the settings I came up with ...

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Create guest user aka. anonymous (not logged-in) when user is nil.
    user ||= User.new

    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      # logged in user
      if user.has_role? :user
        can :manage, Farm, :user_id => user.id
        can :create, Farm
      end
       # guest user aka. anonymous
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```